# SQL Show names with Distinct or other solution

Tags: sql, distinct

I'm trying to show names only one name from each names with Distinct...

```
SELECT Distinct FirstName, LastName, Dates
FROM Employee INNER JOIN Plan ON Employee.EmployeeId = Plan.EmployeeId

WHERE (Plan.Dates >= '2016-03-28' AND Plan.Dates <= '2016-04-03')
```

I want to show names only one time  / row.

I it looks like following:

those are in the same row from Yohannes dates

```
Yohannes 2016-03-29
Yohannes 2016-03-30
Yohannes 2016-03-31
```

and for Mic

```
Micke 2016-03-28
Micke 2016-03-29 
....
```

I realy don't need to show dates, only names is enough
But I want to show only one name from each person / row

In this case

```
Yohannes and
Micke
```

I tried with Distinct but not working as it is. I realy apricate for any help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: why did you tag `asp.net`. you must tag `sql` instead.

Comment: @esiprogrammer Thank you. Tags are are changed

Comment: since `dates` column has different values, your distinct doesn't return your desired result. just remove  `dates` from your select statemen. it should work. `SELECT Distinct FirstName, LastName
FROM Employee INNER JOIN Plan ON Employee.EmployeeId = Plan.EmployeeId

WHERE (Plan.Dates >= '2016-03-28' AND Plan.Dates <= '2016-04-03') `

Comment: @esiprogrammer.. kk my godness... it's working.....I was working in one hour and couldn't understand what was the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `distinct` keyword would return a row for each unique combination of all the columns you're selecting. Since you have different dates for the same name, you're getting the name multiple times. Since you don't really care about the dates, just remove this column from your query and you should be fine:

```
SELECT     DISTINCT FirstName, LastName
FROM       Employee
INNER JOIN Plan ON Employee.EmployeeId = Plan.EmployeeId
WHERE      (Plan.Dates >= '2016-03-28' AND Plan.Dates <= '2016-04-03')
```

Comment: but why I get the same name even if I change dates. There is other date range for this person in database but even if I change to any dates I retrev the same person. My hole code is now in my edited question. Please check.